# Is it Ossur (forbidden) to sleep alone in a room or house?

Tags: sleep, sheidim-demons

It says in Mesechet [Shabbos 151b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=151b&format=pdf) "R' Chanina said: It is forbidden to sleep alone in a house..."

Is this the Halacha?

And are Jews typically careful about this nowadays? If not, why not?

Comment: [Mishna B'rura 239:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=288)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not brought in Shulchan Aruch,  the prohibition is mentioned in Magen Avraham ([239:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.239.7)) and Mishna Berura ([:9](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.239.9)). For comprehensive discussion about the particulars of this, see Shmiras Haguf Vehanefesh (vol. 1 pg.  339). Practical solutions to get out of this problem include leaving the door to the room unlocked, or leaving a light on in the house. Some hold that the problem only applies in a room that does not have a mezzuza,  though others argue. It is also a subject of argument whether this is a problem for women or just men. Obviously for all matters of practical halacha, CYLOR.

Answer (score 1):

See Magen Avraham 239:7 one should not sleep alone,see inside why.There are many sources who say not sleep alone ,from the gemara to the achronim.The one exception some say is a succha because of the protection of the mitzvah.

Comment: Where does this apply practically today? Does it mean that a college student should keep his door open if his roommate is away (or doesn't have a roommate)? What does somebody do on a business trip, etc.? What does a child who has no siblings do? Etc...

Comment: See kaf Hachaim about lamps and gemarah berachas 43 about light.